# Push mongoose query results to global array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose to query my mongodb collections but the results aren't being rendered.  I think I know why, because something, something, async/wait/promise, but nothing works.  Basically I want 2 queries, one to pull the object that is noted in the link requested (workflowID), which itself has several "steps" which are referenced in an array of object ID's.  They aren't being pushed to the scoped variable (workflowStepCombined).  The query is working as intended, if I log the results inside the forEach I get exactly what I would expect.  Like I mentioned, I believe the issue is that the app isn't waiting for the results, I've read through the mongoose doc on promises several times and implemented what I believe is the solution, however after refactoring all day with no progress.

```
app.get("/new/:workflowID", function (req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const workflowID = req.params.workflowID;
    //define array to push recombined steps to
    let workflowStepCombined = [];
    Workflow.findOne({ workflowName: workflowID }, function (err,foundWorkflow) {
        const stepsArray = foundWorkflow.workflowStepArray;
        //once workflow found, start pulling from step collection the listed IDs
        stepsArray.forEach(function (step) {
          Steps.findOne({ _id: step }, (err, foundStep) => {
              //push to array that was definedin first part
              workflowStepCombined.push(foundStep);
          });
        });
        //render it all together
        res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
          userID: req.user.username,
          workflow: workflowStepCombined,
        });
      }); 
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
```

and I also tried using .then because from my limited understanding I need to make it wait for the results of the query before moving to the next lines of code.  But that didn't work either, it does the same behavior.

```
app.get("/new/:workflowID", function (req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      //allows for dynamic link creation
    const workflowID = req.params.workflowID;
    const stepsArray = [];
    //define array to push recombined steps to
    let workflowStepCombined = [];

    //find workflow with name from link
    Workflow.findOne({ workflowName: workflowID }).then(foundWorkflow => {
      stepsArray.push(foundWorkflow.workflowStepArray);
    })
    console.log(stepsArray)
    //once workflow found, start pulling from step collection the listed IDs
    stepsArray.forEach(function (step) {
    Steps.findOne({ _id: step }).then(foundStep => {
        workflowStepCombined.push(foundStep);
        console.log(foundStep);
     });
    });
      //render it all together
      res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
        userID: req.user.username,
        workflow: workflowStepCombined,
      });
```

Comment: Isn't "findOne" also async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forEach function is not async, so you call res.render before getting steps result. You should use Promise.all function

```
Promise.all(stepsArray.map(step => Steps.findOne({ _id: step })))
  .then(workflowStepCombined => {
    return  res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
      userID: req.user.username,
      workflow: workflowStepCombined,
    });
  })
```

I suggest you use async/await approach instead of callbacks

```
app.get("/new/:workflowID", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const workflowID = req.params.workflowID;
    //define array to push recombined steps to
    let workflowStepCombined = [];
    const workflow = await Workflow.findOne({ workflowName: workflowID });
    const stepsArray = foundWorkflow.workflowStepArray;
    const workflowSteps = await Steps.find({_id: {$in: stepsArray}}) //https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/ and you could use sort here if needed - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

    //render it all together
    res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
      userID: req.user.username,
      workflow: workflowSteps,
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I need to work on my understanding of promises a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right that the problem is something about promises not being resolved before the server sends the response. This part of the code is the culprit:

```
stepsArray.forEach(function (step) {
  Steps.findOne({ _id: step }, (err, foundStep) => {
      //push to array that was definedin first part
      workflowStepCombined.push(foundStep);
  });
});
```

`Array.forEach` is tricky with asynchronous callbacks, in your case, you are expecting each loop to execute and resolve before the next so that at the end of the loop, the result of all the `findOne` queries would be in the `workflowStepCombined` array, however, that won't be the case, you can check out [this article for why](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/).

The straightforward fix would be to use `Promise.all` like this:

```
Promise.all(stepsArray.map(stepId => Steps.findOne({_id: stepId})))
  .then(workflowStepCombined => {
    res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
      userID: req.user.username,
      workflow: workflowStepCombined,
    });
  })
```

However, since the `sepsArray` is an array of workflow step `_id`s, you can make use of a single find query instead of executing multiple queries in a loop. Something like this:

```
Steps.find({ _id: { $in: stepsArray } })
```

This should return an array containing all the step objects identified in the `stepsArray` so no need for loop and push. Combining this with the previous query, the endpoint should be something like this:

```
app.get("/new/:workflowID", function (req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const workflowID = req.params.workflowID;

    Workflow.findOne({ workflowName: workflowID }, function (err,foundWorkflow) {
        const stepsArray = foundWorkflow.workflowStepArray;

        Steps.find({ _id: { $in: stepsArray } }, function(error, workflowStepCombined) {

          res.render("contracts/" + workflowID, {
            userID: req.user.username,
            workflow: workflowStepCombined,
          });

        })
      }); 
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
```

**Remember to catch and handle possible errors**

Comment: thank you! not only does it work but it's a much more elegant solution. Really appreciate the concise explanation for why my code was not working.

Comment: You are welcome @ElliotSzutz. Since the answer works, you should [accept/upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.